# LwIP Netconn API + FreeRTOS TCP Client Buffer Issue

Tags: tcp, tcpclient, stm32f4discovery, lwip

I've been trying to modify the tcp server example with LwIP in STM32F4DISCOVERY board. I have to write a sender which does not necessarily have to reply server responses. It can send data with 100 ms frequency, for example.

Firstly, the example of TCP server is like this:

```
static void tcpecho_thread(void *arg)
{
  struct netconn *conn, *newconn;
  err_t err;

  LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(arg);

  /* Create a new connection identifier. */
  conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);

  if (conn!=NULL) {  
    /* Bind connection to well known port number 7. */
    err = netconn_bind(conn, NULL, DEST_PORT);

    if (err == ERR_OK) {
      /* Tell connection to go into listening mode. */
      netconn_listen(conn);

      while (1) {
        /* Grab new connection. */
        newconn = netconn_accept(conn);

        /* Process the new connection. */
        if (newconn) {
          struct netbuf *buf;
          void *data;
          u16_t len;

          while ((buf = netconn_recv(newconn)) != NULL) {
            do {
              netbuf_data(buf, &data, &len);

              //Incoming package
              .....

              //Check for data
              if (DATA IS CORRECT) 
              {
                //Reply
                data = "OK";
                len = 2;

                netconn_write(newconn, data, len, NETCONN_COPY);
              }

            } while (netbuf_next(buf) >= 0);

            netbuf_delete(buf);
          }

          /* Close connection and discard connection identifier. */
          netconn_close(newconn);
          netconn_delete(newconn);
        }
      }
    } else {
      printf(" can not bind TCP netconn");
    }
  } else {
    printf("can not create TCP netconn");
  }
}
```

I modified this code to obtain a client version, this is what I've got so far:

```
static void tcpecho_thread(void *arg)
{
  struct netconn *xNetConn = NULL;

  struct ip_addr local_ip; 
  struct ip_addr remote_ip; 
  int rc1, rc2; 

  struct netbuf *Gonderilen_Buf = NULL;
  struct netbuf *gonderilen_buf = NULL;
  void *b_data;
  u16_t b_len;

  IP4_ADDR( &local_ip, IP_ADDR0, IP_ADDR1, IP_ADDR2, IP_ADDR3 );  
  IP4_ADDR( &remote_ip, DEST_IP_ADDR0, DEST_IP_ADDR1, DEST_IP_ADDR2, DEST_IP_ADDR3 );

  xNetConn = netconn_new ( NETCONN_TCP );  
  rc1 = netconn_bind ( xNetConn, &local_ip, DEST_PORT ); 
  rc2 = netconn_connect ( xNetConn, &remote_ip, DEST_PORT );

  b_data = "+24C"; // Data to be send
  b_len = sizeof ( b_data );  

   while(1)
   {
     if ( rc1 == ERR_OK )
      {
        // If button pressed, send data "+24C" to server
        if (GPIO_ReadInputDataBit (GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_0) == Bit_SET)
        {

          Buf = netbuf_new();
          netbuf_alloc(Buf, 4); // 4 bytes of buffer
          Buf->p->payload = "+24C";
          Buf->p->len = 4;

          netconn_write(xNetConn, Buf->p->payload, b_len, NETCONN_COPY);
          vTaskDelay(100); // To see the result easily in Comm Operator

          netbuf_delete(Buf);
        }
    }
    if ( rc1 != ERR_OK || rc2 != ERR_OK )
    {
      netconn_delete ( xNetConn );
    }
  }
}
```

While the writing operation works, netconn_write sends what's on its buffer. It doesnt care whether `b_data` is NULL or not. I've tested it by adding the line `b_data = NULL;`

So the resulting output in Comm Operator is like this:

```
Rec:(02:47:27)+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C+24C
```

However, I want it to work like this:

```
Rec:(02:47:22)+24C
Rec:(02:47:27)+24C 
Rec:(02:57:12)+24C 
Rec:(02:58:41)+24C
```

The desired write operation happens when I wait for around 8 seconds before I push the button again.

Since netconn_write function does not allow writing to a buffer, I'm not able to clear it. And netconn_send is only allowed for UDP connections.

I need some guidance to understand the problem and to generate a solution for it.
Any help will be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see one or two problems in your code, depending on what you want it exactly to do. First of all, you're not sending `b_data` at all, but a constant string:

```
b_data = "+24C"; // Data to be send
```

and then

```
Buf->p->payload = "+24C";
Buf->p->len = 4;
netconn_write(xNetConn, Buf->p->payload, b_len, NETCONN_COPY);
```

`b_data` is not anywhere mentioned there. What is sent is the `payload`. Try `Buf->p->payload = b_data;` if it's what you want to achieve.

Second, if you want the `+24C` text to be sent only once when you push the button, you'll have to have a loop to wait for the button to open again before continuing the loop, or it will send `+24C` continuously until you stop pushing the button. Something in this direction:

```
while (GPIO_ReadInputDataBit (GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_0) == Bit_SET) {
  vTaskDelay(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of printing the result in the correct way.

You can try to add this part of code before writing in the netbuf data structure:

```
char buffer[20]; 

sprintf(buffer,"24+ \n");

Buf->p->payload = "+24C";
```